# Использование делегата EventHandler

Tags: c#, события, делегаты, c#-8.0

Помогите разложить в голове схему использования события, основанного на предоставляемом делегате EventHandler на примере простой задачи(видел похожий вопрос на этом сайте, но там использовался какой-то кастомный делегат и было мало чего понятно).

Допустим, есть класс Doctor, у него есть поле - фамилия и номер кабинета, в котором он принимает, а есть класс Patient, у которого есть поле фамилия и номер палаты, где он лежит.

Задача: при изменении номера кабинета врача оповещать об этом пациента(можно просто текстовым сообщением).

```
class Doctor
    {
        public event EventHandler ChangedInCabinetNumber = delegate { };

        public string Surname { get; private set; }

        ushort cabinetNumber;

        public ushort CabinetNumber 
        {
            get => cabinetNumber;

            private set
            {
                cabinetNumber = value;
            }
        }

        public Doctor(string surname, ushort cabinetNumber)
        {
            Surname = surname ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(surname));
            CabinetNumber = cabinetNumber;
        }
    }

class Patient
    {
        public string Surname { get; private set; }

        public ushort CabinetNumber { get; private set; }

        public Patient(string surname, ushort cabinetNumber)
        {
            Surname = surname ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(surname));
            CabinetNumber = cabinetNumber;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто, создайте у `Patient` обработчик события:

```
void ChangeCabinetNumber(object o,EventArgs args)
{
    //Что-то сделать
}
```

и подпишете его на `Doctor.ChangedInCabinetNumber`:

```
doc.ChangedInCabinetNumber+=pat.ChangeCabinetNumber;
```

Это код должен быть в каком-нибудь Main, когда вы создаете объекты докторов и пациентов.

В сеттере свойства  `Doctor.CabinetNumber` дергайте `ChangedInCabinetNumber` если есть подписчики.

```
public ushort CabinetNumber 
{
    get => cabinetNumber;

    private set
    {
        cabinetNumber = value;
        ChangedInCabinetNumber?.Invoke(this,new EventArgs())
    }
}
```

Comment: можете показать код?

Comment: ~ как-то так...

Comment: спасибо! Только подскажите: ChangedInCabinetNumber?.Invoke(this,new EventArgs()). this - кто вызывает метод(если я правильно понял), а  new EventArgs() что делает?

Comment: @IAMLERNCSHARP ну так, как только вы присваиваете значение через CabinetNumber, то вызываются все инструкции, которые там указаны. В том числе и это событие. new EventArgs() требуется в сигнатуре вашего события. Туда, обычно, передают какую-то дополнительную информацию => вы можете создать наследника от EventArgs и передавать туда, например, номер кабинета и там образом, все кто подпишутся на конкретного доктора, сразу могут извлечь номер нового кабинета.

Comment: P.S Если я дал исчерпывающий ответ, то поставьте галочку.

Comment: создать наследника от EventArgs и передавать туда, например, номер кабинета. Для этого нужно создать, к примеру, отдельный класс, наследуемый от EventArgs и содержащий поле для хранения номера кабинета?

Comment: @IAMLERNCSHARP Да. https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.14.php

Comment: подскажите ещё такой момент: могу ли я как-то узнать и обратиться к объектам класса-подписчика?

Comment: @IAMLERNCSHARP Из Доктора к Пациенту? Если вы не будете хранить коллекцию пациентов в Докторе, то нет.

Comment: да, к примеру, у меня есть сторонний класс InfoService, который выводит информацию о враче и пациентах, которых он(врач) лечит. Так вот можно ли как-то мне обратиться к полям тех пациентов?

Comment: @IAMLERNCSHARP Нельзя, так как у вас set помечен, как private=> извне нельзя.